# Powershell: Set focus to child window

Tags: powershell, focus, childwindow

I am in the processing of Automating Virus Scan Exclusions.  Since I cannot write straight to the registry, I am making a macro of sorts using PowerShell.  It works pretty well, but I want to ensure that I have the focus of the window I want before I send a slew of key strokes to it.

Using the following code, I get to the VirusScan Exclusions for McAfee.

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise\mcconsol.exe'
Start-Sleep 5    
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("VirusScan Console")
Start-Sleep -m 500
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}%{ENTER}")
start-sleep -m 500
#[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("On-Access Scan Properties")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{DOWN}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{RIGHT}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{RIGHT}%E")
start-sleep -m 750
```

However, there is a chance that focus could not be on the correct window.

Child windows
'On-Access Scan Properties' and then 'Set Exclusions' (as a child of 'On-Access Scan Properties') appear.

Questions:
   1) What code can I use to set the focus to a particular subwindow (by title)?
   2) What code can I use to test that the window is in fact the focus?

Basically I use and RDP manager to connect to a bunch of different machines.  I want to set this script off and forget it.  In order to do that, I have to ensure that the proper windows are in focus.  It doesn't work well when I am switching between RDP connections.